# Defining month_days to show number of days in each month

Tags: python

I'm taking a crash course intro to Python, and stumped trying to define `month_days` to print the number of days in each month in a sentence saying `Month has x days`.

This is what I have come up with so far, but I am not sure how to define `month`:

```py
def month_days(month, days):
    print(month + “ has “ + str(days) + “ days.”)


month_days(June, 30)
month_days(July, 31)
```

Comment: Put the month names in quotes.  `month_days("June", 30)`

Comment: Try to use `f"{month} has {days} days."` instead `Month + “ has “ + str(days) + “ days.”`. Also notice your parameter in function is `month` not `Month` as in your print statement.

Comment: Also stop capitalizing keywords / function names.

Comment: @accdias why would you edit someone's code? Code should be left as it was copied or typed by OP. Small corrections if not all of it was marked as code are ok, but changing capital to small letters is not.. that makes difference in Python.

Comment: Because they clearly were typos caused by some autocorrection function. You could see that OP had `month` as the parameter for `month_days` but was passing `Month` for `print()`. OP also had a `Def` and it was clearly a typo as well because OP seems to know how to `def`ine a function. My corrections didn't change the topic of the question, which is how do I pass a value the right way for `month`.

Comment: You don't know if they were typos.. you didn't put that code in the question. The first word in line I could blame autocorrection for it but not the word in the middle, considering parameter month, haven't been 'autocorrected'. Just saying, sometimes may do more harm than help by editing the code.

Comment: It clearly is. Even the quotes used in the code snippet are from a word processor, not a text editor. Also, OP can easily edit the question and revert to the original snippet if they think I did something wrong to their code.

Comment: Still just guessing mate. Always better to point it out and make sure people asking questions copied text correctly. You don't know What they have in their editor. The original post could be someone's code, and then there would be many reasons why it didn't work.

Comment: Comment from the OP on the answer: _"Apologies, trying to learn on an iPad, thank you for the feedback – Meg"_. Software keyboard "autocorrection" stuff for sure.

Comment: As I said, still guessing. Code was edited before that comment. So that is probably how it was written and then copied. At least someone does some moderation.

Comment: Let's just finish this off-topic now. Just read what I wrote about asking OP a few comments above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many things wrong. Remember the general rule: almost everything is case sensitive. Variables `month` and `Month` are totally different objects.

Second problem: `Print` should be lowercase.

Third: you're passing strings to the function, not variables, so you need to quote them. That mean you need to write `month_days('June', 30)` instead of `month_days(June, 30)`. Without quotes python will look for variable named `June`, what's not your goal.

At last: correct quote characters. You can use `'` and `"`, but never `“`. The last one, which you were using, is more for writing in natural language than any(!) programming language.

So, code should look like this:

```
def month_days(month, days):
  print(month + ' has ' + str(days) + ' days.')

month_days('June', 30)
month_days('July', 31)
```

You can also print it like this:

```
print(f'{month} has {days} days.')
```

Or like this:

```
print('%s has %d days.' % (month, days))
```

Answer (score 0):

def month_days(month, days):
print(month + " has " + str(days) + " days.")

month_days("June", 30)
month_days("July", 31)

run smoothly, without error but got the following suggestion (or error ).

Here is your output:
june has 30 days
july has 31 days

Not quite. Let your function do most of the work and just
pass the name of the month and the associated days as
parameters.